# Selecting firstnames and lastnames from users table using the friends table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Okay so I managed to select the friends id for user 75, how ever I can't figure out how to select users.firstname, users.lastname from the users table for the friends id's
And I cant remove the IF statement as one of my friends sugested as that will ruin the other queries after.

```html
SELECT IF(friends.sender = 75, friends.recipient, friends.sender) users.firstname, users.lastname AS user_id
FROM friends
JOIN users 
ON (users.id = friends.sender)
WHERE friends.sender = 75
    OR friends.recipient = 75
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yours is the only one containing a question mark *Sam*.

Comment: "How ever I cant figure out how to select users.firstname, users.lastname"
Which is already in the post...

Comment: As always with these write-my-sql questions (which we love to answer): provide at least table structures, sample data and desired results

Comment: You need to join back to users from friends again based on friend Id.

Comment: It would be better to separate the cases of `sender = 75` and `recipient = 75` into separate queries, and combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: Why are you using `users.firstname` as the alias for the `IF` expression? `IF` returns the sender or recipient ID, not a name. And an alias can't be of the form `table.column`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the selection of the friend ID in a subquery, then join that with `users`.

```
SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname
FROM users as u
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT IF(friends.sender = 75, friends.recipient, friends.sender) AS friend
      FROM friends
      WHERE 75 in (sender, recipient)) AS f
ON f.friend = u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you want to list all users first and lastname that received from user 75, if it's the case, this will work for you :

```
SELECT u.id,u.firstname,u.lastname FROM users u
JOIN friends f 
  ON u.id = f.sender OR u.id = f.recipient
WHERE f.sender=75
      AND u.id<>75
```

And the `AND u.id<>75` does all the job so you get only the friends names.